# Event handler not picking up correct state value

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a simple Battleships board game and need to increment a state variable when a player clicks on a cell with a valid move.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-leakey-6ek9o

- All of the code pertaining to this question is found within the following file: >src>GameboardSetup>**GameboardSetup.js**

The state variable in question is called `placedShips`. It is designed to keep track of how many ships have been placed onto the board. The variable is initialised to 0 and is supposed to increment up until it reaches a set integer value:

```
    const [placedShips, setPlacedShips] = useState(0);
```

When the user clicks on the grid, an onClick handler fires. If the cell was a valid cell, then a ship should be placed into an array and the value of `placedShips` should increment. When the value increments, a new ship is then selected to be placed on a subsequent click. Each new ship has a different length.

Currently, when the user clicks on a valid grid cell, a ship is correctly placed into the array. The issue arises on subsequent valid clicks, whereby the same ship is then placed into the array. This issue is being driven by the onClick handler apparently not receiving an updated state value for `placedShips`.

While I can see from a { useEffect } hook that the state is in fact increment, the `placedShips` variable within the event handler I believe is constantly set to 0. Below is how I believe I have validated this issue.

Here is the onClick event handler, containing a console log for the state variable:

```
const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(placedShips)
    let direction = ships[placedShips].direction;
    let start = parseInt(e.target.id);
    let end = start + ships[placedShips].length - 1;
    console.log(playerGameboard.checkIfShipPresent());
    if ((playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) && (!playerGameboard.checkIfShipPresent(direction, start, end))) {
        playerGameboard.placeShip(placedShips, direction, start, end);
        setPlacedShips(oldValue => oldValue + 1);
    }
}
```

and here is the { useEffect } hook with another console log for the state variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(placedShips)
}, [placedShips])
```

By selecting multiple valid cells, this is the console log output:

```
GameboardSetup.js:70 0     <--- Event handler console log
GameboardSetup.js:74 false
GameboardSetup.js:143 1     <--- useEffect console log
GameboardSetup.js:70 0
GameboardSetup.js:74 false
GameboardSetup.js:143 2
GameboardSetup.js:70 0
GameboardSetup.js:74 false
GameboardSetup.js:143 3
```

You can see that the event handler console log always reports `placedShips` as 0. Whereas the { useEffect } hook shows it incrementing with each successive click.

Apologies for the longwinded question, I have been stuck on this problem for 2 weeks now and haven't made any significant progress with it. Any advice would be **hugely** appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClickHandle is not updated when the UI Render. Move it into your return. and it works fine. No need to use humanSetUpGrid. Just get the result from createUiGrid. So cells will be updated when app render.

```
const createUiGrid = () => {
    const cells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cells.push(i);
    }
    let counter = -1;
    const result = cells.map((cell) => {
      counter++;
      return (
        <div
          className="cell"
          id={counter}
          onClick={onClickHandler}
          onMouseOut={onMouseOutHandler}
          onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler}
        />
      );
    });
    return result;
  };
```

```
 <div className="setup-grid">
    <Table grid={createUiGrid()} />
  </div>
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes but am unfortunately seeing an infinite loop on my end.

Comment: @Tijm92 Remember to change your createUIGrid. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it is working now (with a few bugs that I can fix) - really appreciate it!